# QUERY REGARDING PARENT AND CHILD PROCESS

Tags: operating-system

Can a for loop be preempted  in between?

suppose  we have a parent and child proces;both have for loop execution

Can one process's for loop be preempted in between so that another process for loop is started?and if so, will it resume afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

This depends obviously on the operating system used and many parameters, e.g. the priority of the processes. But generally a process can be interrupted after each machine instruction. This means it can be interrupted even within a single line of code in a language like C.
If a process has been interrupted, it will normally be resumed with the next machine instruction.